Alternative to Terraform `lifecycle` for modules
I have a Terraform file that I want to prevent anyone from ever running terraform destroy on.
The normal way to do this would be to include the lifecycle block containing prevent_destroy = true on one or more resources in the file. But, I cannot do this. The file contains only modules, which do not accept lifecycle.
I considered modifying the modules themselves to contain a lifecycle block that could be configured with an argument. But that won't work either because the block accepts only literal values, not variables.
Another alternative would be to add a do-nothing resource to the file that would accept the lifecycle block. It dosen't much matter what resource this is, I guess? Any resource containing the block with prevent_destroy set should be enough to halt the destroy command. Right?
So, what's the most economical resource type for me to use to do nothing but hold this block? Ideally, one that dosen't incur additional cloud provider costs or security exposure.
The provider is Cloud Foundry. Terraform version is 1.7.5.

In some cases there are also API options for the said provider which allow you to protect some of the resources, e.g, LBs in AWS can have enable_deletion_protection argument set to true, which would be an equivalent of using the lifecycle.

I think you can use the "Do-Nothing" Resources here.

Pick a Placeholder: Terraform offers a couple of resources that are basically there to hold your spot. You have two options:


null_resource: This is like a blank notecard specifically designed for situations where you just need a space filler.

local_value: Even though it's meant to define local values, it can also act as a do-nothing resource in a pinch.


Add Resource and lifecycle block:
In your main Terraform file (the one with the modules), add your chosen resource and the lifecycle block with prevent_destroy = true:
resource "null_resource" "prevent_destroy" {

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}


This code just defines a null_resource named prevent_destroy and tells Terraform to avoid this if someone tries to run terraform destroy.
Hope this helps!

I'd be curious to see an example of doing this with a local value

Expanding on Amit Yadav's answer:
Yes, terraform destroy will fail when using a "Do-Nothing" resource with prevent_destroy = true
BUT
You can still destroy individual resources without prevent_destroy = true, using terraform destroy -target ...
Example:
resource "null_resource" "a" {
  triggers = {
    description = "This is resource A"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "b" {
  triggers = {
    description = "This is resource B"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "c" {
  triggers = {
    description = "This is resource C, that cannot be destroyed"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

Running terraform apply:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.a will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "a" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "This is resource A"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.b will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "b" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "This is resource B"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.c will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "c" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "This is resource C, that cannot be destroyed"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
null_resource.c: Creating...
null_resource.b: Creating...
null_resource.a: Creating...
null_resource.c: Creation complete after 0s [id=9037144392933681267]
null_resource.a: Creation complete after 0s [id=3131749863575336651]
null_resource.b: Creation complete after 0s [id=2968146761042792979]

Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Running terraform destroy fails, as expected:
Error: Instance cannot be destroyed

  on main.tf line 13:
  13: resource "null_resource" "c" {

Resource null_resource.c has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this resource to be destroyed. To avoid this error and continue
with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target option.

But running terraform destroy -target null_resource.a -auto-approve succeeds:
null_resource.a: Refreshing state... [id=3131749863575336651]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.a will be destroyed
  - resource "null_resource" "a" {
      - id       = "3131749863575336651" -> null
      - triggers = {
          - "description" = "This is resource A"
        } -> null
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
null_resource.a: Destroying... [id=3131749863575336651]
null_resource.a: Destruction complete after 0s

# Other log lines

Destroy complete! Resources: 1 destroyed.

Running terraform plan again:
null_resource.c: Refreshing state... [id=9037144392933681267]
null_resource.b: Refreshing state... [id=2968146761042792979]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.a will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "a" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "description" = "This is resource A"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

